# FR: Staplers corner

Tags: margins, luatex, two-column

I like twocolumn documents, but sometimes people complain that stapeling pages together made it hard to read the top left text of the left column on all pages after the first page.

OK, I could have a broader margin on the left, but what about something more fancy?

I'd like to have a "staplers corner" starting on page 2. It should look like this:

[image: staplers corner]

Basically, it's just a quarter of a circle every new page left blank, a kind of parshape. If possible, I'd appreciate a solution without tikz, pstricks or fp, because documents with these packages take such a long time to compile.

Below I put the tex file and you can see how I arranged the "staplers corner", but this is a horrible kind of solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, DIV=calc, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext, microtype}

\begin{document}
\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

%\blindtext{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis
non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.  Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum
augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis
sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus,
aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit
amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus
velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in,
velit. Ut\newpage{} \mbox{\hspace*{4em}} porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ip-\mbox{\hspace*{3.8em}}sum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing \mbox{\hspace*{3.1em}}elit. Duis fringilla
tristique neque. Sed inter-\mbox{\hspace*{2em}}dum libero ut
metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit
sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.  Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, alquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.

\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\blindtext{}
\end{document}
```

If there is no way to have command like `\AtBeginningOfEveryNewPage{...}`, maybe the only solution were LuaTeX?

Comment: The traditional approach would be to use something like `\setlength\oddsidemargin {0.03in}\setlength\evensidemargin{-0.03in}` to make room for the staple.

Comment: I would add that the `twoside` class option would be needed to take advantage of my prior comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i would recommend the same as you, but he says he doesn't want wide margins.  otoh, taking lumps out of a paragraph, depending on the page breaks, may be impossible -- even if not, it's beyond me.

Comment: @wasteofspace  I was playing around with `\parshape`, but found, even if invoked in the middle of a paragraph, it [retroactively] takes hold at the beginning of the paragraph.  This behavior will make it very difficult to adapt to the current problem since, even if one could invoke `\parshape` at the beginning of each page, it would change the shape at the beginning of the paragraph (on the prior page) rather than in the middle of the paragraph on the new page.  To use `\parshape`, one would need to know what line of the paragraph the page break occurs on.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\parshape` surely has to start at the beginning of the paragraph, which is part of why i suspect the trick isn't achievable.  otoh, those cleverer than i often confound such pessimism on my part!

Comment: The biggest obstacle is that at the time you know what text will be at the upper left corner of the page, you're in the totally wrong place (in time) of the typesetting process defined by LaTeX: All paragraphs are already formatted and boxed. So there is nothing you can do with `\parshape` at that point in time.

Comment: Just for completeness I'll state that this kind of trick is easy with [DocScape](http://www.docscape.de), so it's possible to do with `\parshape`. But DocScape has a totally different base model of "output processing" than LaTeX.

Comment: If the left margins don't leave room for a staple, then they also don't leave room for your left thumb when holding the paper for reading. Be nice to your readers and increase the left and top margins. Also, a quarter circle looks a bit ragged; if I managed to do this, I would use a triangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also IMHO, it's better left some margins than do this.

But said that, you can obtain some similar to you example adding a phantom lettrine at the beginning of each page.  In this MWE, the macro `\stapler` must be inserted after the last word of each page.(When the page end with an automatic hyphen, you can change this  a manual hyphen followed by `\stapler`.). For some reason, this cannot be made automatically with `afterpage` or `everypage`. Therefore, at the moment is easy, but only a solution for a final draft.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, DIV=calc, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine,lipsum} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\newcommand\stapler{%
\parfillskip=0pt
\par\lettrine[slope=-20pt,lines=5]{\hspace{2.5cm}}{~~~~~~}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. 
Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis
non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit.  Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum
augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis 
\stapler 
is sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus,
aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit
amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Ut porttitor.

\lipsum[1-7]

Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus
velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in,
velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. 
\stapler 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut
metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit
sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.  Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, alquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper. 

\end{document}
```

The empty space here is a triangle and not a a quarter of a circle (I think that is better than a curved shape) but playing with macro values you can obtain almost the same that in your example. Try for example  `\lettrine[slope=-10pt,lines=4]{\hspace{1.5cm}}{~~}`.

Comment: Very well done. I'm gonna play with afterpage and the like and maybe ask again.